# listbox control didn't redraw after moving main window position or popout a messagebox

Tags: c, windows, winapi, redraw

Here is the screenshot of my win32 app (dialogbox-based , non-MFC):

[image]

After I click **add button** , data like **11:22    test** will be added to the listbox below.

but after I move the main dialogbox , the listbox items will disappear as the image shown beblow which i think the listbox didn't redraw itself.

[image]

after i click **add button** to add new list item to the listbox, list items appears again. and after that,moving dialog didn't cause the blank-listbox anymore.
moving main dialog to the edge of the desktop and letting listbox hidden from we can see. or pop out a messagebox will alse **erase** listbox-item.

[image]

the full c code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "resource.h"
//global variable declaration
HWND hWnd,hHour,hMinute,hRemindText,hRemindList;
WNDPROC procHour,procMinute;
char buf[1024],bufHour[1024],bufMinute[1024],bufRemindText[1024];
int i;
//function declaration
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
LRESULT CALLBACK HourEditProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK MinuteEditProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                      LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
    DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ALARM),hWnd, (DLGPROC)DlgProc);
    return 0;
}
//function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HICON hIcon,hIconSm;
    switch (LOWORD(Msg))
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG :
        //initial
        memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
        //icon setting
        //hIcon = (HICON)LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
        //SendMessage(hWndDlg, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG  , (LPARAM)hIcon);
        //hIconSm = (HICON)LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
        //SendMessage(hWndDlg, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hIconSm);
        //subclass the edit control
        hHour = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg, IDC_HOUR);
        hMinute = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_MINUTE);
        hRemindText = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_REMIND_TEXT);
        hRemindList = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_REMIND_LIST);
        procHour = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLong(hHour, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)HourEditProc);
        procMinute = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLong(hMinute, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)MinuteEditProc);
        return TRUE ;
    case WM_CHAR:
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND :
        switch (LOWORD (wParam))
        {
        case IDC_REMIND_LIST:
            if(HIWORD(wParam) == LBN_DBLCLK)
            {
                i=SendMessage(hRemindList,LB_GETCURSEL,0,0);
                SendMessage(hRemindList,LB_DELETESTRING,i,0);
            }
            if(HIWORD(wParam) == LBN_SELCHANGE)
            {
                SendMessage(hRemindList,LB_GETTEXT,0,(LPARAM)buf);
                MessageBox(hWndDlg,buf,buf,MB_OK);
                //InvalidateRect (hRemindList, NULL, FALSE);
                //UpdateWindow(hRemindList);
                //ShowWindow(hRemindList,0);

            }
            return TRUE;
        case IDC_ADD://添加
            //MessageBox(hWndDlg,NULL,NULL,MB_OK);
            if(GetWindowText(hHour,buf,sizeof(buf)) == 0)
            {
                MessageBox(hWndDlg,"【时】不能为空！","提示",MB_OK);
                break;
            }
            sprintf(bufHour,"%02s:",buf);
            if(GetWindowText(hMinute,buf,sizeof(buf)) == 0)
            {
                MessageBox(hWndDlg,"【分】不能为空！","提示",MB_OK);
                break;
            }
            sprintf(bufMinute,"%02s",buf);
            if(GetWindowText(hRemindText,buf,sizeof(buf)) == 0)
            {
                MessageBox(hWndDlg,"【提醒内容】不能为空！","提示",MB_OK);
                break;
            }
            sprintf(bufRemindText,"    %-140s",buf);

            memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
            strcat(buf,bufHour);
            strcat(buf,bufMinute);
            strcat(buf,bufRemindText);
            SendMessage(hRemindList,LB_ADDSTRING,0,(LPARAM)(LPCSTR)buf);
            return TRUE;
        case IDOK :
            EndDialog (hWndDlg, 0) ;
            return TRUE ;
        case IDCANCEL :
            EndDialog (hWndDlg, 0) ;
            return TRUE ;
        }
        break ;
    }
    return FALSE ;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK HourEditProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    switch (message) 
    {
    case WM_SETFOCUS:
        SendMessage(hwnd,EM_SETLIMITTEXT,2,0);
        break;
    case WM_KEYUP:
        GetWindowText(hHour,buf,sizeof(buf));
        sscanf(buf,"%d",&i); 
        if(i/10>2 || i>=24)
        {
            buf[1]=0;
            SetWindowText(hHour,buf);
            SendMessage(hHour,EM_SETSEL,1,0);

            return TRUE;
        }
        break;  
    }
    return CallWindowProc (procHour, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
} 
LRESULT CALLBACK MinuteEditProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    switch (message) 
    {
    case WM_SETFOCUS:
        SendMessage(hwnd,EM_SETLIMITTEXT,2,0);
        break;
    case WM_KEYUP:
        GetWindowText(hMinute,buf,sizeof(buf));
        sscanf(buf,"%d",&i); 
        if(i/10>5 || i>=60)
        {
            buf[1]=0;
            SetWindowText(hMinute,buf);
            SendMessage(hMinute,EM_SETSEL,1,0);

            return TRUE;
        }
        break;  
    }
    return CallWindowProc (procMinute, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

the full resource script code:

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 中文(简体，中国) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_CHS)
LANGUAGE LANG_CHINESE, SUBLANG_CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_ALARM DIALOGEX 0, 0, 300, 201
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "定时提醒器"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    EDITTEXT        IDC_HOUR,6,7,25,14,ES_CENTER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_NUMBER,WS_EX_RIGHT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MINUTE,45,7,25,14,ES_CENTER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_NUMBER
    EDITTEXT        IDC_REMIND_TEXT,121,7,172,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    PUSHBUTTON      "↓添加",IDC_ADD,6,26,54,14
    CONTROL         "1",IDC_MON,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,38,152,20,10
    CONTROL         "2",IDC_TUE,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,65,152,20,10
    CONTROL         "3",IDC_WED,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,92,152,20,10
    CONTROL         "4",IDC_THU,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,119,152,20,10
    CONTROL         "5",IDC_FRI,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,146,152,20,10
    CONTROL         "6",IDC_SAT,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,173,152,20,10
    CONTROL         "7",IDC_SUN,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,200,152,20,10
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "保存设置",IDOK,83,180,61,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "最小化到托盘",IDCANCEL,156,180,61,14
    LTEXT           "提醒我",IDC_STATIC,227,152,25,8
    LTEXT           "点",IDC_STATIC,36,10,9,8
    LTEXT           "分",IDC_STATIC,74,9,9,8
    LTEXT           "请在周",IDC_STATIC,6,152,25,8
    LTEXT           "提醒我",IDC_STATIC,88,9,25,8
    LISTBOX         IDC_REMIND_LIST,7,46,287,99,LBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST2,7,46,287,99,LBS_SORT | LBS_HASSTRINGS | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_ALARM, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 293
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 194
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "Clock.ico"
#endif    // 中文(简体，中国) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Comment: The border of the list box is messed up on the lower left corner.  Sure looks like two windows overlapping each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after exam the rc file i found

two windows overlapping each other as HansPassant said.